# merge multiple coco json files in python

Tags: json, coco

I have 1000 coco format json files assigned to 1000 images.

I want to make these json files into the merged one json file.

I don't know what to do.

(It seems that there are not many tools that merge a large amount of json files.. I don't know if coco assistant is running in my case.)